# List a maximum of ‘x’ product categories with qty of ‘y’ in each column

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, menus, array

Im trying to list a maximum of ‘x’ product categories (a multiple of y) with a qty of ‘y’ in each column. ‘x’ decides how many columns are displayed.

What I am trying to do:
 - If there are less product categories than ‘x’ in the shop then
   display all.
 - If there are exactly ‘x’ then display ‘x’.
 - If there are more than ‘x’ display x-1 and display a “view all categories” link in the last place.

As an example: With 35 product categories. 
If max product categories=32 and qty per column=8, display 31 product categories in 4 columns and the "view all" link in 32nd place.

The total product categories are constantly changing so I am trying to make the code work dynamically for any amount, without the need to change the code, unless to change 'x' or 'y'.

Here is the basic code that I have been able to make work for me, however the link spills into the next column, rather than last place in the previous column.
As a beginner I have exhausted my knowledge of if/else logic and everything else I have tried is messing up the output.

```
<?php

$args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
         'orderby'      => 'name',
         'number'       => 32,   //maximum to list
         'title_li'     => '',
         'show_count'   => 0,    // 1 for yes, 0 for no
         'pad_counts'   => 0,    // 1 for yes, 0 for no
         'hierarchical' => 1,    // 1 for yes, 0 for no
         'hide_empty'   => 0,    // 1 for yes, 0 for no
         'echo'  => 0,           // 1 for yes, 0 for no
         'exclude' => '73, 74, 16', //best sellers, new, and uncategorized
         'depth'  => '1',        //top level categories, not sub
         'style'  => '',         //default is list with bullets, '' is without
  );

// Grab top level categories
$get_cats = wp_list_categories($args);

// Split into array items
$cat_array = explode("<br />",$get_cats);

// Amount of categories (count of items in array)
$results_total = count($cat_array);

// How many tags to show per list-8)
$remainder = ($results_total-8);
$cats_per_list = ($results_total-$remainder);

// Counter number for tagging onto each list
$list_number = 1;

// Set the category result counter to zero
$result_number = 0;
?>

<div class="cat_columns" id="cat-col-<?php echo $list_number; ?>">

<?php     
foreach($cat_array as $category) {        
                $result_number++;

if($result_number >= $cats_per_list) { 
     $result_number = 0; 
     $list_number++;
    echo '<div>'.$category.'</div> </div> <div class="cat_columns" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';
}
 else {         
 echo '<div>'.$category.'</div>'; 
}
}
echo '<a href="https://www.aaaa.com/all-categories//">View Categories</a>';
 ?>
```

Comment: Not sure why this question has been down voted. I have posted the same question recently, which I believe was misinterpreted to some extent by the member who answered. They told me basically bad luck, to accept the answer and post a new question. So here it is, further clarified. I am not sure how to have this not considered a duplicate?

Here is the previous question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346801/display-woocommerce-product-categories-in-a-4-columns-custom-menu?rq=1

Comment: So, in your example, 'x' is 32 and 'y' is 8, right?

Comment: Yes thats exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is different from *your* code (and the one in the accepted answer to the other question), but it worked well for me:

*You can remove the `"\t" .` and `. "\n"` which I added for pretty formatting purposes so that you could better inspect the generated HTML markup.* And let me know if you have any question on any parts of the code. :)

```php
// First, define these.
$max_cat_count = 32; // this is 'x'
$qty_per_column = 8; // this is 'y'

// Then the $args array.
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'number'     => $max_cat_count + 1, // keep the + 1
    'title_li'   => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'echo'       => 0,
    'style'      => '',
    // ... your other args here ...
);

// Get the categories list.
$get_cats = wp_list_categories( $args );

// Split the list into array items.
$cat_array = explode( "<br />", $get_cats );

$total = count( $cat_array );
$list_number = 1;
$_new_col = false;

foreach ( $cat_array as $i => $category ) {
    if ( $i >= $max_cat_count ) {
        break;
    }

    if ( $i % $qty_per_column === 0 ) {
        // Close previous column, if any.
        if ( $_new_col ) {
            echo '</div><!-- .cat_columns -->' . "\n";
        }

        // Open new column.
        $id = 'cat-col-' . $list_number;
        echo '<div class="cat_columns" id="' . $id . '">' . "\n";

        $_new_col = true;
        $list_number++; // increment the columns count
    }

    if ( $total > $max_cat_count && $i === $max_cat_count - 1 ) {
        // Make sure to change the # to the proper URL.
        echo "\t" . '<div><a href="#">View All</a></div>' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "\t" . '<div>' . trim( $category ) . '</div>' . "\n";
    }
}
// Close last column, if any.
if ( $_new_col ) {
    echo '</div><!-- .cat_columns -->' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sally, this works perfectly! :) I will update the other question with a link to this answer or you may post the same answer there ?

Comment: Hi Whee, I'm glad it worked for you! And regarding the other question, I think you should just leave it as it is (don't edit it) and actually, when you linked to that question (from this page), this question was also linked automatically from that other question. :)

Comment: ah yes I can see that now, super helpful :)